# Why I cant use USB Debugging on Android HoneyComb Acer Iconia

Tags: android, android-emulator

Im trying to debug application on Acer Iconia but the usb Debugging mode wont start I wonder why

cant anybody tell me some tricks

I also did this debugging on my HTC Incredible but it run and why i wont run while I use honeycomb

for the Incredible I use gingerbread

can anybody helpme ?

I'll appreciate your reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the drivers for your specific model from Acer's site (for the A500 it's http://support.acer.com/product/default.aspx?modelId=3851) then it should work.

Comment: I have installed the driver but don't any device in Eclipse. On old computer all good (Win XP) but under Win 7 I can't see device. Can you help me?